# Why there are no breakpoints in time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following time series:

```
Lines <- "D1,Diff
1,14/01/2015 00:00,0.03
2,14/01/2015 01:00,0.03
3,14/01/2015 02:00,0.01
4,14/01/2015 03:00,0.02
5,14/01/2015 04:00,0.03
6,14/01/2015 05:00,0.02
7,14/01/2015 06:00,0.01
8,14/01/2015 07:00,0.03
9,14/01/2015 08:00,0.02
10,14/01/2015 09:00,0.01
11,14/01/2015 10:00,0.03
12,14/01/2015 11:00,0.03
13,14/01/2015 12:00,0.03
14,14/01/2015 13:00,0.02
15,14/01/2015 14:00,0.01
16,14/01/2015 15:00,0.03
17,14/01/2015 16:00,0.03
18,14/01/2015 17:00,0.03
19,14/01/2015 18:00,0.01
20,14/01/2015 19:00,0.02
21,14/01/2015 20:00,0.03
22,14/01/2015 21:00,0.03
23,14/01/2015 22:00,0.02
24,14/01/2015 23:00,0.01
25,15/01/2015 00:00,0.03
26,15/01/2015 01:00,0.02
27,15/01/2015 02:00,0.03
28,15/01/2015 03:00,0
29,15/01/2015 04:00,0.03
30,15/01/2015 05:00,0.03
31,15/01/2015 06:00,0.03
32,15/01/2015 07:00,0
33,15/01/2015 08:00,0.03
34,15/01/2015 09:00,0.03
35,15/01/2015 10:00,0.03
36,15/01/2015 11:00,0.01
37,15/01/2015 12:00,0.02
38,15/01/2015 13:00,0.03
39,15/01/2015 14:00,0.03
40,15/01/2015 15:00,0.03
41,15/01/2015 16:00,0.02
42,15/01/2015 17:00,0.01
43,15/01/2015 18:00,0.03
44,15/01/2015 19:00,0.03
45,15/01/2015 20:00,0.03
46,15/01/2015 21:00,0.01
47,15/01/2015 22:00,0.02
48,15/01/2015 23:00,0.03
49,16/01/2015 00:00,0.03
50,16/01/2015 01:00,0
51,16/01/2015 02:00,0.03
52,16/01/2015 03:00,0.03
53,16/01/2015 04:00,0.02
54,16/01/2015 05:00,0.01
55,16/01/2015 06:00,0.03
56,16/01/2015 07:00,0.03
57,16/01/2015 08:00,0
58,16/01/2015 09:00,0.03
59,16/01/2015 10:00,0.03
60,16/01/2015 11:00,0.01
61,16/01/2015 12:00,0.02
62,16/01/2015 13:00,0.03
63,16/01/2015 14:00,0.02
64,16/01/2015 15:00,0.01
65,16/01/2015 16:00,0.03
66,16/01/2015 17:00,0.03
67,16/01/2015 18:00,0
68,16/01/2015 19:00,0.03
69,16/01/2015 20:00,0.03
70,16/01/2015 21:00,0
71,16/01/2015 22:00,0.03
72,16/01/2015 23:00,0.02"
```

I use the following commands:

```
library("strucchange")
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep = ",")
bp <- breakpoints(z~ 1, h = 36)
> bp

     Optimal 1-segment partition: 

Call:
breakpoints.formula(formula = z ~ 1, h = 36)

Breakpoints at observation number:
NA 

Corresponding to breakdates:
NA
```

I would like to find the segmentation. Per one day I found Optimal 3-segment partition. However for 3 days (72 hours) no segment was found. How can I find the 12 segments (breakpoints)?

Comment: If you are looking for the times of the bottoms of the spikes then: `time(z)[coredata(z) < 0.15)]`

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck, can you please elaborate? Why if bottoms of the spikes are < 0.15 then there is no segmentation?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but `plot(z); points(z); abline(h = 0.015)` shows clearly that the spikes are one point wide and the only points below 0.015.

Comment: Thanks and we can see from the graph and from the table that the range is very similar (0, 0.01, 0.02 and 0.03) Does such a case is an indication that there are all in one segment? Or maybe we can fine tune the breakpoints function for finding segments?

Comment: I am not really clear what you want but the point of my remark is that the series is sufficiently regular that you can likely come up with a custom method.

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to know if there can be found segments in the given series and if not why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding breakpoint (aka changepoint) detection, here I borrow from the headline of a blog post from Dr. Andrew Gelman (https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2016/03/18/i-definitely-wouldnt-frame-it-as-to-determine-if-the-time-series-has-a-change-point-or-not-the-time-series-whatever-it-is-has-a-change-point-at-every-time-the-question/):

> **I definitely wouldn’t frame it as “To determine if the time series has a change-point or not.” The time series, whatever it is, has a change point at every time. The question might be, “Is a change point necessary to model these data?” That’s a question I could get behind.**

So, given that time series segmentation is model-based, when and how many breakpoints occur are more or less model-dependent (e.g., assumptions-dependent); that is also why there are numerous alternative breakpoint detection models available in R--the same argument applies essentially to all data analyses. With that said, here are some quick results from two Bayesian changepoint packages: `bcp` and `Rbeast` (as a disclaimer, I developed the latter). Unlike those freqentisit-based models seeking the single set of best possible locations of breakpoints, Bayesian approaches try to estimate probabilities of breakpoint occurrence for any given point of time.

```
# Your sample time series; this is a pure data vector without the time info.
z = c( 0.03,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.02,0.01,0.03,0.02,0.01,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.02,0.01,0.03,
 0.03,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.03,0.02,0.01,0.03,0.02,0.03,0.00,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.00,
 0.03,0.03,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.02,0.01,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.03,
 0.03,0.00,0.03,0.03,0.02,0.01,0.03,0.03,0.00,0.03,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.02,0.01,
 0.03,0.03,0.00,0.03,0.03,0.00,0.03,0.02)

library(bcp)
out = bcp(z)
plot(out)
```

No breakpoints found, as shown below, but somehow in the posterior probability curve, there is a tiny bit of probability somewhere to find changepoints. Overall, statistical evidence suggesting a breakpoint is very weak.

[image]

A try with `Rbeast`, which aims to both detect breakpoints and decompose time series  (i.e., separate seasonality from trend), but your data contains no periodic/seasonal component; that is why `season='none'` is used in the `beast` function.

```
library(Rbeast)
out = beast(z, season='none')
plot(out)
```

Similarly, the overall evidence of suggesting the presence of breakpoints is low, but `Rbeast` finds  a few locations that are more likely to be breakpoints than others, as indicated by the tiny peaks in the Pr(tcp) curve. Not surprisingly, the magnitudes of these peak probabilities are very small. On average, `beast` finds 1 breakpoint and if it has to pinpoint its location, the most probable location is the  last peak--the one marked by the vertical dash line.

[image]

Again, how to segment a time series depends on how you define breakpoints. I am pretty sure if you try a different approach, the result will vary. If you intend to find any locations that have a literal change (i.e., not constant). You can try something like this

```
which(abs(diff(z)) >0.02)
```

which, as you expected, gives 12 breakpoints (Not sure if these are the 12 breakpoints you expected to see.